# How to display django generic detail view inside a modal with ajax

Tags: django, ajax, listview, modal-dialog

I want to display the content of an announcement inside a modal when a user clicked on the announcement list.

This will be the trigger for the modal in my **announcement_list.html**:

```
<form name="form" action="#" id="form_have_product_{{y.id}}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a href="#" id="{{ announcement.pk }}" type="button" class="btn btn-info view-announcement" data-url="{% url 'announcement-detail' pk=announcement.id %}" style="float: right;">View</a>
</form>
```

This is my function in my **views.py**:

def get_announcement(request, pk):
announcement = Announcement.objects.filter(announcement_id=pk)

```
context = {
    'title': announcement.title,
    'about': announcement.about,
    'author': announcement.author,
    'post_date': announcement.post_date
}

return render(request, 'announcement-details-modal.html', context)
```

For the **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [path('announcement/<int:pk>/', get_announcement, name='announcement-detail'),]
```

And this is the **function** for when the user clicks on the announcement list:

```
$(".view-announcement").on("click", function() {
var target_url = $(this).attr("data-url");
var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: target_url,
    headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#modal").modal("toggle");
      $("#modal-content").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Currently this code returns **the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: The JS is not relevant in this question. Remove the js part and show us the error returned with the 500 response. also, the CSRFToken header is not needed in GET request.

Comment: This what's written in the console. 
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/announcement/4/ 500 (Internal Server Error)  jquery.js:4

Comment: please add the whole stacktrace to the question